# Как решить эту задачу используя указатели?(по массиву можно двигаться только с помощью них)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Дано натуральное число n (<= 100). Получить все простые числа, не превышающие это значение. Использовать метод, называющийся
"Решето Эратосфена": пусть дано последовательность натуральных чисел 2,3, ... n. Первое простое число 2, вычеркнем его и все кратные
ему числа. Первое из чисел, оставшихся снова является простым, и можно выполнить те же действия над этим числом и тд.

Comment: Сделайте без указателей. Замените a[i] на *(a+i)

Comment: @pavel хех, сейчас попробую. Просто я написал код, работает, но он без указателей, а в условии указано, что действия должны выполняться исключительно через них

Comment: i[a] и пусть преподаватель гадает, что это значит. "Просто я написал код" и где он?

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков я здесь зарегался очень недавно и ещё не прошарился как нормально вставить код сюда, чтоб он не в одну строку был

Comment: Ctrl+V да и pastebin есть